# Odoo 10: How to know if record is already in database or a new one?

Tags: python, odoo

I'm working on to compute the average of x records and I don't want to include the last one (the record where I trigger the action).I can trigger the action in existing record or in a new one (not yet in database).
Here is my code:

```
@api.one
@api.depends('stc')
def _compute_average_gross(self):
    if self.stc:
        base_seniority = 12
        match_seniority = self.seniority.split()
        total_seniority = int(match_seniority[0]) + int(match_seniority[2]) * 12
        if total_seniority < 12:
            base_seniority = total_seniority if total_seniority else 1  # avoid dividing by 0
        # if the hr.payslip is already in db
        if self._origin.id:
            limit = 13
            # could be self.env.cr.execute() 
            sum_sbr = sum(self.search([('employee_id', '=', self.employee_id.id)], order='create_date desc', limit=limit)[1:].mapped('line_ids').filtered(lambda x: x.code == 'SBR').mapped('amount'))
            sum_average_gross = sum(self.search([('employee_id', '=', self.employee_id.id)], order='create_date desc', limit=limit)[1:].mapped('average_gross'))
        else:
            limit = 12
            # could be self.env.cr.execute() 
            sum_sbr = sum(self.search([('employee_id', '=', self.employee_id.id)], order='create_date desc', limit=limit).mapped('line_ids').filtered(lambda x: x.code == 'SBR').mapped('amount'))
            sum_average_gross = sum(self.search([('employee_id', '=', self.employee_id.id)], order='create_date desc', limit=limit).mapped('average_gross'))
        self.average_gross = round((sum_sbr + sum_average_gross) / base_seniority, 2)
```

With that I got an error that self doesn't have _origin, I trier with origin but got the same error. I also tried with self.context['params'].get('id') but it doesn't work as expected.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if record is not saved in database do this:

```py
if isinstance(self.id, models.NewId): 
    # record is not saved in database.
    # do your logic

# record is saved in databse
if not isinstance(self.id, models.NewId):
    # ....
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you

Comment: It seems like that this not work anymore for odoo 15?

Answer (score 1):

for all who are coming to this after the accepted answer:

the correct solution should be this

```
if isinstance(self.id, models.NewId) and not self._origin: 
    # record is not saved in database.
    # do your logic

# record is saved in databse
if not isinstance(self.id, models.NewId) or self._origin:
    # ....
```

I'm not sure if _origin already existed in Odoo 10, but needed the same in Odoo 13

I haven't tested in a single record but with res.partner and the partner contacts (field child_ids) and the problem is if you open an existing contact and change any field, odoo transfers the existing record in a new record and you get a false positive answer as the record.id is a new ID but the origin exists in DB

haven't tested with copy functionality but i'm sure oodo is correctly resetting the origin in the new record so my answer should be right